# regular expression for matching a string

Tags: regex, linux

I'm trying to remove a part of a given string using the either of the two rules:

1. Eliminate all the consonant(s) at the beginning of a string
2. Eliminate all but the consonants at the beginning of a string.

Suppose my string is str. Is `${str%%[aeoui]{1}*}` correct for the second rule? I'm not sure what to do for the first rule.

Comment: Actually if I remove the {1} in the expression it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are trying to implement this in, so I'll just use some generic syntax.

```
1.  s/^[^aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/\1/
2.  s/^[aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/\1/
```

There are ways to make it case insensitive, but I like being specific like this just for clarity.

The only difference between the two is `^` inside the `[]` in #1 which just negates it.

`*` means zero or more.  If you use `+`, for instance, there would have to be at least one consonant in #1 and at least one vowel in #2 or the test would fail.

In my generic syntax here `\1` returns what was found by `(.*)`.

Here's some very crude Perl to demonstrate (where `$1` in the print statements behaves as `\1` in my example above):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                 

$string1="abcdef";
$string2="fedcba";

if ($string1 =~ /^[aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/) {
    print "Test 1 on $string1: $1\n";
}

if ($string2 =~ /^[aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/) {
    print "Test 1 on $string2: $1\n";
}

if ($string1 =~ /^[^aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/) {
    print "Test 2 on $string1: $1\n";
}

if ($string2 =~ /^[^aeiouAEIOU]*(.*)/) {
    print "Test 2 on $string2: $1\n";
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Test 1 on abcdef: bcdef
Test 1 on fedcba: fedcba
Test 2 on abcdef: abcdef
Test 2 on fedcba: edcba
```

Comment: The first regex removes much more than all the consonants and the second much less than all but consonants.

Comment: How are you testing this that leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: For example, remove all special characters and digits from the string (test with `/123abc`, AFAIK `/123` aren't consonants), the second keeps these characters. That isn't what OP wants. part of this, don't use `\1` in the replacement part, use `$1`, `\1` is reserved for the regex part.